# change the layout html encoding in symfony

Tags: symfony1, character-encoding, symfony-1.4

I'm doing a web application in Symfony 1.4, and its character encoding is set to utf-8 (default). That is ok, but I would like to change the character encoding to s-jis depending on some situations.

I tried with the code below in the module (action.class.php), but it does not work properly:

```
if('some situation')
{

   $context = $this->getContext();
   $response = $context->getResponse();
   $response->setContentType('application/xhtml+xml; charset=Shift_JIS');
   mb_internal_encoding('SJIS-win');
   mb_http_output('SJIS-win');
}
```

Does someone know how to change the character encoding to sjis temporaly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this at the beginning of your `actions.class.php`

```
$this->getResponse()->initialize(new sfEventDispatcher(), array('charset' => '<something>'));
```

Comment: thanks, but i got the way to do it in symfony throught srFilter class.

Comment: Please put the answer here so everyone can learn - even me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I could not answer till now. There you go.

We have to use a class that inherits from sfFilter class.

1. Put the new class file in apps/frontend/lib
2. Add the new class to apps/frontend/config/filters.yml
3. Change the encoding of setContentType and the Content of sfResponse in the new class function.